# Cannot import com.google.cloud.speech.v1.SpeechGrpc in Android

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-platform, google-speech-api, google-cloud-speech

I'm trying to use [Google's Speech API](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/android-docs-samples/tree/master/speech/Speech) in Android project. The example project works. I'm having trouble to use it in my own android app.

build.gradle(Module:app) :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.protobuf'

ext {
    supportLibraryVersion = '25.4.0'
    grpcVersion = '1.4.0'
}
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ApplicationID"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
//        compileOptions {
//            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_5
//            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_5
//        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file(project.properties.storeFile)
            storePassword project.properties.storePassword
            keyAlias project.properties.keyAlias
            keyPassword project.properties.keyPassword
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
        dev {
            // Minimum version with platform multi-dex support
            minSdkVersion 21
        }
        prod {
            // Minimum version that can run gRPC (TLS extension)
            minSdkVersion 16
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            multiDexEnabled true
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.2'
        resolutionStrategy.force "com.android.support:support-annotations:$supportLibraryVersion"
    }
}

protobuf {
    protoc {
        artifact = 'com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.3.0'
    }
    plugins {
        javalite {
            artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc-gen-javalite:3.0.0"
        }
        grpc {
            artifact = "io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:${grpcVersion}"
        }
    }
    generateProtoTasks {
        all().each { task ->
            task.plugins {
                javalite {}
                grpc {
                    // Options added to --grpc_out
                    option 'lite'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

//
//        buildTypes {
//        release {
//            minifyEnabled false
//            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
//        }
//    }
//    compileOptions {
//        targetCompatibility 1.6
//        sourceCompatibility 1.6
//    }
//}

dependencies {
    //    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
    //    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
//    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-speech:v1-rev8-1.22.0'
    compile group: 'com.google.cloud', name: 'google-cloud-speech', version: '0.17.1-alpha'
//    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.2'
    compile project(':lib')    //This is someother library I'm using
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'io.grpc:grpc-core:1.4.0'

    // Support libraries
    compile "com.android.support:design:$supportLibraryVersion"
    compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$supportLibraryVersion"
    compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$supportLibraryVersion"

    // gRPC
    compile "io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:$grpcVersion"
    compile "io.grpc:grpc-protobuf-lite:$grpcVersion"
    compile "io.grpc:grpc-stub:$grpcVersion"
    compile 'javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.2'
    protobuf 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.3.1'

    // OAuth2 for Google API
    compile('com.google.auth:google-auth-library-oauth2-http:0.7.0') {
        exclude module: 'httpclient'
    }

    // Tests
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
}
```

build.gradle(Project: ProjectNAME):

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        // for gRPC
        classpath "com.google.protobuf:protobuf-gradle-plugin:0.8.0"
//        compile 'com.github.adrielcafe:AndroidAudioConverter:0.0.8'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
    }
}
```

Now, When I try to `import com.google.cloud.speech.v1.SpeechGrpc;` I'm getting an error `Cannot resolve symbol 'SpeechGrpc'`. But `import com.google.cloud.speech.v1.RecognitionAudio` or `RecognizeRequest` etcetera works fine.

I've tried adding the [expample project's app module](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/android-docs-samples/tree/master/speech/Speech/app) as module which didn't allow me to use even `import com.google.cloud`. So, I either need solution to import `Grpc` or correct gradle settings to use google's speech API

Comment: Tezz, how did you solved it?

Comment: [Below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44917825/3881561) solution worked for me.

Comment: it still didnt solve this one:
 import com.google.cloud.speech.v1.SpeechClient; 
any solution for that? @tezz

Comment: @AtheelMassalha Back then, the accepted solution worked for me. You could try another beta dependency(not sure if it works) - compile "com.google.cloud:google-cloud-speech:0.61.0-beta"

Comment: it works for all import but the "SpeechClient", I will try another beta and update. thanks.
was you using "SpeechClient" ?

Comment: @tezz 0.61.0-beta works!  thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you add the [***proto directory***](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/android-docs-samples/tree/master/speech/Speech/app/src/main) on GoogleCloudPlatform/android-docs-samples to your android application source(app/src/main/), it will work fine even though you don't write [compile group: 'com.google.cloud', name: 'google-cloud-speech', version: '0.17.1-alpha'] on your build.gradle(Module:app).

Comment: great!!!! thanks!
it still didnt solve this one:

import com.google.cloud.speech.v1.SpeechClient;

any solution for that?
@tezz  ?

Answer (score 4):

Add the following dependency in your build.gradle.

> ```
> implementation 'com.google.api.grpc:grpc-google-cloud-speech-v1:1.23.0';
> ```